# How do I clear the canvas but keep the fill?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Right now my code works like I want it to but when I created my timer to redraw the triangle it overlayed a new triangle every time it was called, so to stop this I put clearRect in, but now it clears the entire canvas negating my fill of black that I have. How can I either add a new timer that still provides the same effect of moving triangles but that doesn't require clearRect or how can I fix what I have to have the background of the canvas stay black but not overlay new triangles every time? Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I also tried two different timers together instead of a timer for handleClick, but got weird results with the speed of the triangles, does anyone know why that is?:

```
timer = setInterval(init, 30);
timer = setInterval(Triangle, 30);
```

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var canvas;
    var context;
    var triangles = [];
    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        resizeCanvas();
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
        window.addEventListener('orientationchange', resizeCanvas, false);
        canvas.onclick = function(event) {
            handleClick(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        };
        timer = setInterval(handleClick, 30);
    }
    function Triangle(x,y,color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
        this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5; //5-3
        this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
        for (var i=0; i < triangles.length; i++) {
            var t = triangles[i];
            t.x += t.vx;
            t.y += t.vy;
            if (t.x + t.vx > canvas.width || t.x + t.vx < 0)
                t.vx = -t.vx;
            if (t.y + t.vy > canvas.height || t.y + t.vy < 0)
                t.vy = -t.vy;
        }
    }
    function handleClick(x,y) {
        context.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
        var colors = ['red','green','purple','blue','yellow'];
        var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
        triangles.push(new Triangle(x, y, color));
        for(i=0; i < triangles.length; i++) {
            drawTriangle(triangles[i]);
        }
    }
    function drawTriangle(triangle) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(triangle.x,triangle.y);
        context.lineTo(triangle.x + 50,triangle.y + 50);
        context.lineTo(triangle.x + 50,triangle.y - 50);
        context.fillStyle = triangle.color;
        context.fill();
    }
    function resizeCanvas() {
         canvas.width = window.innerWidth-10;
       canvas.height = window.innerHeight-10;
        fillBackgroundColor();
        for(i=0; i < triangles.length; i++) {
            drawTriangle(triangles[i]);
        }
    }
    function fillBackgroundColor() {
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }
    window.onload = init;
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While I'm not too familiar with canvas I think you should create a `redraw` method that will first clear the canvas then draw everything you want and whenever you need to make any changes you change some variables and call redraw method that redraws entire canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few minutes reading threw your code, and found one thing that stood out to me. To begin, when you call the `timer = setInterval(handleClick, 30);` the commands are run from top to bottom in the `handleClick` function. So when we look at that function, the first thing you draw is the black background. Then, you push out a brand new triangle. Following this, you draw all the triangles in the array using a loop. This is where the issue is. What you are doing is drawing all the past triangles, ontop of the refreshed black rectangle.

Try setting your code to something like this.

```
function handleClick(x,y) {
        context.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
        var colors = ['red','green','purple','blue','yellow'];
        var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
        triangles.push(new Triangle(x, y, color));
        triangles.shift(); //This removes the first point in the array, and then shifts all other data points down one index.
        for(i=0; i < triangles.length; i++) {
            drawTriangle(triangles[i]);
        }
    }
```

Pleaase let me know if I miss interpreted any of your code, or if you have a follow up question.